# Elasticsearch upgrade with huge data

Tags: elasticsearch, upgrade, elasticsearch-5, elasticsearch-7

I want to upgrade my Elasticsearch from version 5.6 to version 7.8. I have around 900 GB of data. The core application is utilising the Elasticsearch and hence I would like to complete this with a limited downtime period. [Snapshot and restore](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/snapshots-restore-snapshot.html) is one option which I have found. Any suggestions or inputs which I am unaware will be useful.

Comment: Hi, Do you have any extra node to be able to transfer data to it first and then transfer them back?

Comment: I can create a spare node

Answer (score 0):

Elasticsearch versions can communicates from 1 major version to another.
So to migrate with 0 downtime, you can connect a 6.8 node to your 5.6 cluster.

- If indices are compatible, use Shard allocation awareness to move shard to new cluster.
- If not, reindex (with shard allocation awarness to ensure that one primary or one replica is on your new nodes)
- Then kill 5.6 nodes one by one.

And redo this steps a second time between 6.8 and 7.9 nodes

Comment: Can you please share any notes or blog posts which describe this process in detail?

Comment: you can follow the rolling upgrades documentation of elastic https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/rolling-upgrades.html